# wordpress - navigate from one page to another in same plugin

Tags: wordpress

i am currently use a page wpPlugin.php in plugin of wordpress and i want to navigate to test.php in same plugin, when i jump to that page it shows an error, "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page"

here is code of test.php:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: AutoBlogging Settings
Plugin URI: http://test.com
Description: Plugin for displaying info
Author: abc
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://test.com
 */

function AutoBlogging_Settings() {
    echo "test test test";
}

function AutoBlogging_Settings_Actions() {
    add_options_page("AutoBlogging Settings", "AutoBlogging Settings", "manage_options", __FILE__, "AutoBlogging_Settings");
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'AutoBlogging_Settings_Actions');
?>
```

how can i access this page.

Comment: are you logged in as an Administrator (who have manage_options capability) ?

Comment: yes, i am logged in as administrator